# Tag synonym: maven -> maven-2

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms

There are currently [259 questions tagged maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven) . As most of the users will likely use Maven 2.x , as Maven 1.x has been long retired, I suggest that we map `maven` to `maven-2` and leave only the `maven-1` tag for Maven 1.x .

There is no point in allocating questions for a deprecated version to the main tag.

Comment: and what if there is [maven-3] one day?

Comment: There already is a maven-3 . Alternatively, we can simply retire the maven tag and discourage its usage.

Comment: hm, the [tag-wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/maven/info) states [maven] is *A tag for questions related to the legacy Maven 1 (not maven 2.x or 3.x).*, but maybe the [maven]-tag should only be used when the question is *not* version specific?

Comment: @Tobias: out of my knowledge, it's hard to have a question not specific to a version. Maven 2.x and 3.x are quite similar, but Maven 1.x is a completely different animal.

Comment: I must admit I don't know much about Maven, but since the newer version are less different (as far as the two of us know...) your suggestion is probably good, assuming [maven-4] will not throw up the same problem again...

Comment: just search for maven 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 1 zillion

Answer (score 8):

Please, ***stop the madness***. Don't make synonyms from `name+majorversion` to `name`. It is all kinds of wrong, and will only get *more* wrong as future versions are released and old versions fall by the wayside.

Comment: Right now `maven` is not a synonym but practically equivalent to `maven-1`. How would you suggest this fixed, as most of the questions - if not all - tagged `maven` in fact relate to Maven 2?

Comment: @Robert: blacklisting [maven], forcing people to pick the version-specific tag?

Comment: @Tobias While almost probable and this is the traditional solution to ambiguous tags, I think there will be a lot of confusion when someone tries to post a question and is told "You can't tag a question with [maven]", as that produces an implication that maven questions aren't allowed.

Comment: @Grace: right, I didn't see it that way. The blacklisting message would have to be individualised then. I guess it's best to rely on those with the necessary experience to retag things correctly.

Comment: @Robert: What is it that you think needs fixed? You're not articulating a practical problem or difficulty that's arising. You seem somehow concerned about the ambiguity of simply tagging a question with `[maven]`, but making `[maven-2]` a synonym of `[maven]` doesn't really alleviate that ambiguity in practice, it merely adds to it.

Comment: @Robert: I'd also add that if, as you say, Maven 1 is rarely used, and Maven 2 and 3 are very close, wouldn't the people answering questions about Maven realize that? Presumably they could infer from the generic `[maven]` tag and the date the question was posted which version is most likely being referred to. If they find it too ambiguous, they should either answer for the most likely version(s) and state that they're doing so, or just leave a comment asking the questioner to specify a version.

Comment: @Nicolas: I'm worried about the fact that we have both maven, and maven-2. Moreover, maven-2 questions are - incorrectly, as we stand - tagged as maven. As a matter of fact, I recall that all maven questions should've been retagged either maven-1 or maven-2. But that does not work in practice, so I think we need another solution.

Comment: @Robert: We have exactly the same situation with most technologies. All the major programming languages, like C#, Python, or PHP, have version-specific tags that are sometimes used, as well as a generic tag that is even more widely used, and could probably be replaced with a version-specific tag, but usually isn't. How is Maven different? And what are you planning to do when Maven 4 is out/popular? Are you going to make `[maven-4]` a synonym for `[maven]`? What happens to earlier questions then? What if the maven 2/3 answers are still valid for 4? What if not? You're just making a bigger mess.

Comment: @Nicholas : Obviously my interest is not in making a mess. But the current situation is far from optimal. What solution do you see?

Comment: @Robert: None. Tagging is sub-optimal in this regard, and the only convincing solution anyone has come up with is a tag hierarchy-ish system, which has been rejected multiple times and in multiple forms by Jeff. Until someone comes up with an alternative Jeff likes, there is no solution.

Comment: @Nicholas: Maybe rewording the `maven` tag to be related to general Maven questions and recommend using the more precise tags would help. What do you think about that?

Answer (score 1):

While having a `[maven-1]` specific tag for Maven 1.x question could make sense (that's just **not** how thing evolved), I'm personally totally against making `[maven]` a synonym of `[maven-2]`, I don't see any reason to do so:

- Most `[maven]` questions are Maven 1.x specific (or are at least supposed to be), not Maven 2.x
- Even if a `[maven-1]` tag was introduced for Maven 1.x specific questions, I don't see why `[maven]` should become  a synonym of `[maven-2]`
- Yes, Maven 3.x supports Maven 2.x projects but the inverse is not true and we'll have Maven 3.x specific questions and I hope users will use the existing `[maven-3]` for them.

So please, don't make `[maven]` a synonym of `[maven-2]` (I'd prefer to blacklist it rather than making it a synonym).