# Ideas to manage/control version specific tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms, version-tags

*I'm very sorry if this is duplication, but I can't find a mention of anything like this anywhere yet. It seems like it might even be a little obvious.*

From [How to use version specific tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85358/how-to-use-version-specific-tags) question's answer I got the idea of when to use version specific tags. But most of the people don't know that. Being a ruby on rails developer. I have seen lot of people using [ruby-on-rails-3](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails-3) on their questions not [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails).

Can't we show a warning to users while posting a question in case they don't add generic tag for the same.

A warning like:

```
"You are adding ruby-on-rails-3 not ruby-on-rails. It will be great 
 that you analyse your question again and add proper required tags"
```

Let me know if you guys have planned something else or will love to know better ideas to solve this problem.

Comment: Isn't this just one idea? Then maybe the title [should include the proposal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178762/191131).

Answer (score 1):

There are [19,000 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails-3+-ruby-on-rails) tagged [ruby-on-rails-3](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails-3) and not [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails). It appears as though the RoR community is voting on their feet, and they're voting against what you're suggesting.

Having said that, this is something that *you* can influence. If you believe every RoR-3 question should be tagged RoR (and I'd agree with that) then *you* need to do it. Start tagging them. Maybe you can effect a change in community behaviour.

Comment: ROR is just an example. There are 100's of other tags like this. What about them?

Comment: There really aren't @MohitJain... the vast majority of the "big" tags have been tightly controlled. If there are smaller tags that this has happened to then yes, you're probably right but it's not something that isn't fixable by a single person in an afternoon...

Comment: Happens to [tag:sql-server] families too, however in both directions. Sometimes people will tag [tag:sql-server-2005] but not [tag:sql-server]. Other times they will tag [tag:sql-server] but then we have to ask what version. And then still others they will tag [tag:sql-server-2008] when they really meant [tag:sql-server-2008-r2] (or vice-versa). I don't believe there is an answer really except to be diligent about re-tagging when necessary in the tags you care about.

Comment: I'm doing this for the Maven questions I'm touching anyway: Remove the `maven-3` tag and add a `maven` tag. This seems to have some influence - at least more than the [re-tag request on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147095/191131).